# JS what is the difference of methods defined inside and outside of the constructor function

Tags: javascript

I have this class object that needs to have its draw function inside the constructor to update the score, if it is outside the score returns undefined.

```
export class Hud {
constructor(world) {
    var self = this;
    this.canvas = world.canvas;
    this.ctx = world.ctx
    this.score = 0;
    this.draw = function() {
        this.ctx.font = "16px Arial";
        this.ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
        this.ctx.fillText("Score: " + self.score, 8, 20);
      }
   }
}
```

my other class objects have the draw function outside of the constructor like so works fine,

```
export class Ball {
constructor(world) {
    var self = this;
    this.canvas = world.canvas;
    this.ctx = world.ctx;
    self.x = canvas.width / 2;
    self.y = canvas.height - 30;
    this.ballRadius = 10
    this.dx = 2;
    this.dy = -2
}
draw() {
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    this.ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    this.ctx.fill();
    this.ctx.closePath();
}
}
```

My question is what the difference between the two are. I thought if its defined in the constructor the variables are accessible throughout the class object. I guess I'm confused, should there be functions outside of constructor function? Having everything in the constructor seems to be hassle free.

Comment: generic methods go in the class body, while own methods needing closure go in the constructor. It _can_ save ram and CPU overhead to define common (prototype) methods instead of instantiating separate function instances for each object instance. Having the method spelled out in the class can also be a little cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: When class methods are declared on the prototype (e.g. outside of the constructor) only one instance of that function exists and is re-used for all class instances, such that `Ball.prototype.draw === ball1.draw === ball2.draw`. When methods are declared on the instance (e.g. inside of the constructor) a new function is created for every instance, such that `ball1.draw !== ball2.draw`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Function defined in the class (not in the constructor) live on the class prototype which each instance is linked to. Functions defined in the constructor become own properties of each instance. If you defined the function in the constructor, each instance will get its own copy of the function. If you don't the instances will defer to the prototype chain and all the instances will point to the same function. For example:

```js
class Hud {
    constructor(world) {
        this.name = world
        this.draw = function() {
            console.log("draw on instance from", this.name)
          }
       }
    draw_outside(){
        console.log("draw on class from", this.name )
    }
}

let h1 = new Hud('h1')
let h2 = new Hud('h2')

console.log(h1.__proto__.draw)         // draw not on prototype
console.log(h1.__proto__.draw_outside) // draw_outside is

console.log(h1.draw === h2.draw)                  // each object gets its own draw
console.log(h1.draw_outside === h2.draw_outside)  // but both point to the same draw_outside

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(h1))       // only draw & name

// both access `this` the same way when called on an instance:

h1.draw()
h1.draw_outside()
```

Comment: Access to hidden properties. Speed of method call. Object Footprint. Taken from here: https://www.thecodeship.com/web-development/methods-within-constructor-vs-prototype-in-javascript/

Comment: @zxxz can you elaborate on access to hidden properties?

Comment: Not so much "hidden properties", as local variables defined inside the constructor. Any variables scoped to the constructor function are not accessible to prototype methods, but *are* accessible to functions defined within the scope of the constructor itself. Thus, local variables within the constructor are "hidden" from anywhere else in the class/object.